# NHibernate Profiler does not connect to session and record

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I'm using NHProfiler to get SQL output from .NET MVC website. Despite previously connecting to the session and recording the SQL output it no longer does this yet the same settings/config appear to work on other computers.

I searched SO and found related questions but they have not provided a solution. I have checked to make sure the port is correct and included references where required, made sure the DLLs are in the project.

Aside from checking the above, are there any other possible causes for the session not be recognised? i.e could it be related to permissions or setup of some kind?

Comment: You're calling the `HibernatingRhinos.etc.etc.Initialize()` somewhere suitable, right?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes it is being called somewhere suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add a reference to `HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.v4.0.dll` and add the following code in application start up.

```
protected void Application_Start() 
{
  ...
  //do not use on production server ever ever ever
  HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHibernateProfiler.Initialize();

}
```

That's it, nothing else is needed

Comment: Yes that is included but it still doesn't recogise the session and connect to it. NHProfiler takes a long time to load (about 4 minutes) could it be a permissions problem?

Comment: I would not have thought so, NHProf takes about 2-3 secs to load for me. Maybe you can ask for help here, https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/nhprof

Comment: Also check that you are on the latest build.

Comment: 4 minutes to load is insane. Could be security related, but difficult to tell. Can you use 'proper' Sql profiler to see if *anything* is hitting the database?

Comment: Must it be HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.v4.0.dll? And not HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.dll?

Comment: I downloaded the newest version of NHprofiler and it loads in a couple of seconds but still doesn't connect to the session.

Comment: I added a reference to HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.v4.0.dll and it worked. It has found the session. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes, the non v4 is for .net 2 - 3.5 and v4 is for net 4 apps, that will be it then!